# How to get vertical alignment in the header row of a table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

I created a table by using the website [tablesgenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) but I'm not completely satisfied regarding the centering of the header row.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Information about downloaded and filtered NEOs databases.}
\label{tab:NEOs:databases:info}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccrc@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Near-Earth \\ objects\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{No. of objects}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Date of\\ download\end{tabular}}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
 & \textbf{downloaded} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{filtered}} &  \\ \midrule
NEAs & \multicolumn{1}{r}{28963} & 53 & 19-05-2022 \\
NECs & \multicolumn{1}{r}{192} & 0 & 19-05-2022 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would want to get a better centering of the rows circled in red in the following image (I want that the two couples of rows have the same distance from the \toprule and from the \midrule):
[image: table]
Can you help me to get the vertical alignment of the circled objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `\multirow` doesn't have to be an integer. Since the `\cmidrule` directive adds almost `0.5\baselineskip` to the total height of the header material, I'd give `\multirow{2.4}{*}{...}` a try.

Separately, I'd also center-align rather than right-align the numbers in the two middle columns, while still aligning the numbers on their (implicit) decimal markers. In the code below, this is accomplished by employing the `S` column type that's provided by the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-digits=false]}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Information about downloaded and filtered NEOs databases.\strut}
\label{tab:NEOs:databases:info}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c T{5.0} T{2.0} l @{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\mytab{Near-Earth \\ objects}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{No.\ of objects}} & 
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\mytab{Date of\\ download}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& {\textbf{downloaded}} & {\textbf{filtered}} \\ 
\midrule
NEAs & 28963 & 53 & 19-05-2022 \\
NECs &   192 &  0 & 19-05-2022 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mico. The table looks very professional now. Do you know an alternative to the website indicated in my question that is able to perform your suggested alignments?
I make this question because I need to import large .csv tables from separate files and so I need a webservice to accelerate the tables creation.

Comment: @Giuseppe - My sincerely given piece of advice is not to use that website -- unless, by some miracle, you manage to generate exactly the table you want, without need to apply further tweaks. In my experience, the LaTeX code created by the website is virtually unmaintainable and untweakable by humans -- experienced LaTeX users (such as myself...) included. My main suggestion is that you familiarize yourself with the [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package and learn how to use it to load data from csv files into a LaTeX document for inclusion in a table.

Comment: Thanks again. Is it possible to use such a package in Overleaf? I do not use a local LaTex distribution.

Comment: @Giuseppe - The `datatool` package is part of any standard TeX distribution, including TeXLive. Overleaf provides a (sophisiticated...) front-end to TeXLive.

Comment: I implemented your solution but I have two problems: 1) The numbers of "downloaded" and "filtered" columns have two decimal figures (i.e., .00). 2) The dates seems to be in text format and not in mathmode. Any suggestions to fix them?

Comment: I need to specify the number of decimal digits during the creation of the table and not in preable since I have different needs for different tables.

Comment: @Giuseppe - Re Problem 1: To indicate, e.g., that the numbers in some column can have up to 5 ordinary digits and up to 2 decimal digits, just use `T{5.2}`. Re problem 2: Not sure what you're asking. For the answer I posted above, I used the `l` (short for "left") column type; when used in a `tabular` environment, `l` is a text mode and not a math mode column type. On your second comment: Again, not sure what you're asking. Do note that the instruction `\begin{tabular}{@{} c T{5.0} T{2.0} l @{}}` is executed inside the body of the `document` environment, *not* in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks again! 1) Issue fixed by modifying the `\sisetup` in my preamble! 2) My issue was that the output that I have with your solution is the same that I get outside the table by typing `$28963$` which is different from `28963`. Anyway my problem was related to the dash line to separate the numbers in the dates: to avoid to get the minus sign, I had to use `\text{-}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139585/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-mico).

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabls` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Information about downloaded and filtered NEOs databases.\strut}
\label{tab:NEOs:databases:info}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {c Q[c, si={table-format=5.0}] 
                              Q[c, si={table-format=2.0}] l},
                row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, guard}
                }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    {Near-Earth \\ objects}
        &\SetCell[c=2]{c}  No. of objects
                        &           & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  {Date of\\ download} \\
    \midrule
        & downloaded    & filtered  &               \\
\midrule
NEAs    & 28963         & 53        & 19-05-2022    \\
NECs    & 192           & 0         & 19-05-2022    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution, be certainly the simplest.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% caused gap below caption

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Information about downloaded and filtered NEOs databases.}
\label{tab:NEOs:databases:info}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccrc@{}}
\toprule
  \textbf{Near-Earth} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{No. of objects}} & \textbf{Date of} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3}
  \textbf{objects} & \textbf{downloaded} & \textbf{filtered} & \textbf{download} \\
\midrule
NEAs & \multicolumn{1}{r}{28963} & 53 & 19-05-2022 \\
NECs & \multicolumn{1}{r}{192} & 0 & 19-05-2022 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```